# Best way to serialize multiple float arrays in a file

Tags: arrays, serialization, floating-point, protocol-buffers, msgpack

I'm trying to serialize multiple float(single precision) arrays, cross many languages(python/java/c/cpp), with minimum size.

I expected it would need float array header and 4 byte for each float. But msgpack seems 5bytes is necessary. 
https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/issues/198#issue-87308597

Is there any recommendation library for serializing float arrays? with 4 bytes or less per float? Or just use raw byte arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Protocol buffers supports "packed" arrays for some primitives; basically, the cost works out as:

- a varint field header for the array (1 byte for low field numbers)
- a varint length prefix of the number of bytes
- the number of bytes  (4 bytes per value for single precision, 8 bytes per value for double precision)

100 single precision floats stored with the "packed" option in field 5 (arbitrarily) will cost 1 + 2 + 400 = 403 bytes.